# Yii external session Management

Tags: yii, session-management

I am newbie in yii framework. I have a problem with yii external session management.

I have created in simple php page with session. In that page link to the yii application.

when i click the link, the php session will continue in the  yii application. when logout the

yii application total session will destroyed. Please any one can help to solve this problem

and how can do that. sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

In logout Yii uses `Yii::app()->user->logout` this means that user which is on site all the session created will be ended so you have to change your logout action by using `Yii::app()->session` simply use

```
print_r(Yii::app()->session);
die;
```

this will give you all the live session,after getting all the session variables unset one by one which you want to to removed at the time of logout.

It as simple as that.

Comment: i try to external authentication in yii framework. if any have possiblities what can do?

Comment: What kind of external session i am not getting you exactly are you creating session outside the application and you want to access it inside Yii?

Comment: i exactly want to sso with nonyii and yii application. i don't know what to do. please help me..